# How to call Alfresco (repository) webscript from Share in Java

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco, alfresco-share

I know I may get down-voted for this trivial question...

In Javascript it is easy (even magical): `remote.call("/api/...")`

How do I get this in Java?

I read a lots of posts like [this one](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/call-repository-webscript-share-09272012-1043), where the Alfresco (repository) URL is either hard coded `http://localhost:8080/alfresco`, either undefined (exemple : `REPO_WEB_SERVICE_URL`).

Is there a helper that could give me the URL of the repository? Is there a class that do the same as the `remote` Javascript root object?

I’m sorry if the answer is obvious, I just can’t see it, I’m searching for hours already and I'm starting going crazy about it as it should be a no-brainer...

Comment: Ok I am stupid, REPO_WEB_SERVICE_URL may not be an absolute url of Alfresco repository but a relative one... I’ll test this snippet and I’ll answer my own question if I get it right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make the remote available in your Share script you need to inject the remote using Spring.

Set a context file to set your remote variable:

```
<bean id="MyEvaluator" class="org.me.MyEvaluator">
    <property name="remote" ref="webframework.webscripts.scriptremote" />
</bean>
```

Then you need to create the variable in your Java class. Given that you can use it as you like:

```
public class MyEvaluator extends BaseEvaluator {

    private ScriptRemote remote;

    public void setRemote(ScriptRemote remote) {
        this.remote = remote;
    }

    public void doScriptCall() {
        Response response = remote.call("/api/...");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I could inject the `ScriptRemote` class, it answers my question but I finally did an other way because I don’t like to have `ScriptXXX` methods on my Java classes (I don’t know if my ). I was missing the repository url and I managed to get it by searching in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, in order to get the Alfresco Repository base path.

Inject the `connectorService` into the bean:

```
<bean id="MyEvaluator" class="org.me.MyEvaluator">
    <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
</bean>
```

Then in the class, retrieve the Alfresco endpoint:

```
String alfrescoEndPoint = connectorService.getConnector("alfresco").getEndpoint();
```

`alfrescoEndPoint` will be something like `http://host:port/alfresco/s` according to what was set in `alfresco-global.properties`.